# Function Fields Feature in Matlab

Tags: matlab

`mapminmax` is a builtin Matlab function. I am trying to implement something that does autocomplete for functions/subfunctions like this.

[image]

I've done a quick search but haven't really come up with what it's called. `mapminmax` is the only function I know of that implements this feature. It looks like a field of a function (like how a field of a struct).

I've used `edit mapminmax` to see the insides of Matlab's function but I haven't found anything leading to how this is possible. `getParamStructFromArgs` looks like it might be able to explain what this is, but it looks like it's related to NNs.

**Question:** What is this feature called and is there any documentation on this?

Comment: Okay so it's specifically related to Matlab's packaging system? That's one thing I didn't check, because I see Matlab's packaging system as a mess.

Comment: Hmm okay. I was able to create something like it. I'll post what I mean in an answer.

Comment: @hypfco Function in a package folder, methods/properties of a class instance, and fields in a `struct` in my experience.

Comment: @hypfco Check my answer, you were correct about Matlab's packaging system.

Comment: @TroyHaskin Is there a way to declare this inside the `.m` file instead of using folders/directories though?

Comment: You can have a function that returns a `struct` (or create the `struct` at the top of an `m`m-file) with a bunch of function handles to any function (local, nested, or on the path).  That's what I do for roll-once "packages" (mostly for small research side projects that will never see the light of day).

Comment: @TroyHaskin Okay but calling the `struct` by itself wouldn't actually run the function would it? I am working on a small research project which is result driven so the implementation will never see the light of day lol...

Comment: No, it would not.  Consider `tools.square = @(x) x.^2;`.  The field `square` holds the function handle which would need to be called to return a value (e.g. `tools.square(4)`) and Matlab's IDE will autocomplete any field of the `struct` as long as it exists in the workspace or Matlab has knowledge of the fields some other way.

Comment: Alright I know of that method already (I use a lot of objects/structs), but I was looking to extend my current functions. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like what @hypfco said was right. This "feature" is related to Matlab's package system. I'm sure there's a way to do it by creating a package, but for those who don't want to create such a package there's a simple way of doing this.

If you have a function such as `untitled.m`, you can create a folder called `+untitled` in your Matlab directory.

Function's `.m file`

[image]

`+Function` folder

[image]

Then when you do `untitled.` and press tab in the console, you'll get the following pop-up.

[image]

If anyone's got a way to do this inside the `.m` file, I'll accept that answer instead.